# Swift UITableview cell checkmark with selection blink option

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to create `UITableview` `single cell` `checkmark` selection and `Multiple cell` check mark selection. Here, I am trying by below code for single selection check mark but Its reusability not working. Also, I don't know how to do multiple cell selection by clicking cell section.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
```

Comment: @dahiya_boy Its helping me to make selection blink function

Comment: @Sharad Paghadal alright thanks man, I will improve next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For reusability, you need a variable to save the selected cell index(or array for cells) and then set the appropriate `accessoryType` when displaying the cell.

For single selection, remember to clear the previous selection.

A sample pattern for **single selection**:

```
var selectedRow = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells { //Why not using didDeselectRowAt? Because the default selected row(like row 0)'s checkmark will NOT be removed when clicking another row at very beginning.
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.accessoryType = indexPath.row == selectedRow ? .checkmark : .none
}
```

A pattern for **multiple selections** (Updated for multi-sections):

```
var selectedIndexPaths = Set<IndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) { //deselect
        selectedIndexPaths.remove(indexPath)
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    else{
        selectedIndexPaths.insert(indexPath) //select
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.accessoryType = selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) ? .checkmark : .none
}
```

Comment: dude multiple selection some rows working only by double clicks. Also, section click to select under related rows group selection not working

Comment: @BenDev, for rows group, we need to save the section index either. Let me update the answer to this.

Comment: Thank you lot @Yun CHEN. Awesome solution BTW single selection working charm .

Comment: @BenDev, the answer is updated for rows group(multiple sections), please check it. What I wrote are basic patterns. With a real project, you might use the data models to save sections as Sh_Khan did.

Answer (score 2):

Model

```
class Item {
   var name:String!
   var isSelected = false
}
```

then inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.accessoryType = items[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
```

inside `didSelectRowAt`

```
items[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle() 
tableView.reloadRows(at:[indexPath],with:.none)
```

Comment: I have one doubt what is the items? It is my tableview array variable?

Comment: My array static array value     let data: [String] = ["One", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"]

Comment: you have to change it to contain model type not string like above

Answer (score -1):

Set isSingleSelection to false for multiple selections and to true for single selection

```
var isCellSelected = [Bool]()
var isSingleSelection = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for _ in arrayFillingYourTableview { isCellSelected.append(false) }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = branchTbView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    cell.accessoryType = isCellSelected[indexPath.row] ? .checkmark : .none

    return cell

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        if isSingleSelection {
            for i in 0..<isBranchSelected.count {
                isCellSelected[i] = false
            }
        }

        isCellSelected[indexPath.row] = ! isCellSelected[indexPath.row]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @marc but its looks very large solution.

Comment: the way to read it should be from cellForRow for the checkmark to persist even when you scroll through your values, simply adding a checkmark from didSelectRow won't let your value persist when you scroll through many values